# Google sign in button customization

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to customize google sign in button for my website.

```
<div class="g-signin2"></div>

.g-signin2{
    display: inline-flex;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 1.2;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    background: orange;
}
```

But it's not working. Perhaps there is another way to do it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] -> _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: What I'm trying to do is customize google sign in button with css but to no avail, how can I achieve this with javascript or other method if possible?

Comment: Have you already tried this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: I tried but the button style didn't change.